# How is public key used to decrypt in .NET assemblies?

Tags: c#, rsa

.NET signed assemblies contain public key, but the public key is used for encryption in RSA, then how does .NET uses the public key for decryption of signed assemblies?

Ok, the signed assemblies contain the hash, but the hash is encrypted using the private key and not the public key. So, why and how in .NET private keys are used for encryption and public keys for decryption. I mean, that all software like RSACryptoPad uses the public key for encryption and not for decryption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The public-private key pair is not used to encrypt the whole assembly.  Instead it is used to **sign** the assembly.

Simplifying a little, to sign a file - such as an assembly - you take a hash of the file and then ecrypt that hash with your private key.  Someone using the file verifies your signature by making a hash of the file themselves and then decrypting your encrypted hash using your public key and confirming these two hashes are the same.  This proves two things:

1. The assembly is from who is claims to be from - i.e you - as it has been produced with your private key.
2. The assembly hasn't been altered by someone else as the hash you made when you released the assembly is the same as the current one.  No-one can alter the signed assembly since they would also have to make corresponding changes to the encrypted hash which requires your private key.

There is a lot more detail about Digital Signatures in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

The great thing about public-private key pairs is that they work either way around.  So something encrypted with your private key can be only decrypted with your public key but also something encrypted with your public key can be decrypted with your private key.  This latter use means that if someone wants to send something to you and only you then then can encrypt it with your freely available public key but they know only you with your private key can decrypt it.

As the keys only work as a pair - making the [encryption asymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_encryption) - someone else can't simply reverse the encryption they've done with the public key to get the message to you.

Comment: extended the base question, with more queries. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Added some description of why you would encrypt with a public key as well as a private one.

Comment: This is wrong — signing is not done by encrypting with the private key; it is done by /decrypting/ with it (at least for RSA).

Comment: What exactly are you decrypting when signing, derobert?

Comment: @configurator: In RSA, a padded hash of the message. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Signing_messages has details. Remember "decrypt" in RSA is just a mathematical operation, you can perform it on arbitrary data.

Comment: that's what I can't understand how will you do encryption with your private keys, it doesn't have the modulus, exp? How is private keys used for encryption, that's the question?

Comment: @Priyank: In RSA, you can either encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key - or - encrypt with the private key and decrypt with the public key, aka signing. (No nitpicking regarding which part is encrypting or decrypting please)

Comment: It works the same way - data multiplied by private key, then public key, then modulo the modulo part is the same as data multiplied by public key, then private key, then modulo the same modulo part.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that a signature can only be *created* using the *private* key, but after that anyone with a copy of the *public* key can *validate* the signature. **No decryption is required for a signature**--the signature is simply added on to the plain text assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of signing assemblies is to verify their source. If I sign my assembly then send it to you, you should be reasonably sure that's its come from me and it hasn't been tampered with along the way.